# Why statements after while loop is not getting executed?

Tags: java, android

The problem for me nothing gets executed after while loop? what's the issue with that? (The lines after the end of while loop never gets executed)

```
client = serverSocket.accept();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())
);

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.i("line",line);
    line111 +=line;
    Log.i("line111",line111);
}

//Any code below this is not executed
Log.i("shan","Shan");
```

Comment: Either you're throwing, or the loop never ends.

Comment: The loop ends as I am getting the output for first 3 lines..so including break after executing while loop for 50 times would do any good??

Comment: maybe you have ;
after while loop causing problem

Comment: Even removing that doesn't solve it!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your while loop is stuck waiting on the socket for the next line. The source of the stream needs to close the connection at its end.

Answer (score 3):

This code "while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)"
is only relevant when you are reading from a file that have a constant size and finally you will reach it.
When you are reading from a socket, you are entering a blocking state (waiting for remote clients to send data).

You need to add maybe timeout on the docket read method if you want to ever exit the loop.

Comment: It's also relevant when reading from a socket. You just have to understand that the loop will end only when the other side of the socket is closed.

Comment: There could be cases when the remote client is closed and you don't receive an event immediatlly. I know cases in c# when you can stay blocked for a long time.

Comment: I don't want to close the socket on my end.How to find the data transfer has been completed??

Comment: May be I should try including somecharacters at the end of a string I am transferring and find out it the data transfer is completed and then break out of he loop

Comment: By sending some "end-of-message" token, for example.

Comment: This should be part of the protocol that you and the client implemented. you can send the content length before your data and only after reading the entire message, you close it.
Another way is use line endings like: "\r\n" that is a standard way to declare end of message.

Comment: I send only this "#$$#" and closing the reader using in.close would be fine right instead of breaking out of the loop?? whether it would still keep my socket opened?

Comment: It's also relevant for a file without a constant size. On a socket, if the peer closes the connection you will receive an EOS, and you won't block waiting to do so.