# java println blocked after communicating with exe if i do not close the stream

Tags: java, stream, exe, communication, println

I am currently interfacing a GUI to an UCI chess engine. For this purpose i am creating the engine process using:

```
try {
   process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(enginePath);
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println("ENGINE NOT FOUND");
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and i am sure that i am able to open the engine.

When engine is opened, there is no significant stream outputted from engine. In order to initiate communication, I have to send specific commands to the engine. The engine will respond then... Therefore it is working in a command/response approach(not immediately streaming data when opened or talking without spoken to). In order to communicate i have a send message block. In this block write a message to the engine using its outputstream and get input using its standart input stream as in the following send method:

```
    private String sendCommand(String command) {
    stdin = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader errReader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    String answer = "";

    stdin.println(command);
    stdin.flush();
    stdin.close();
    try {   
        String line = "";

        while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            answer = line;
        }

        inputReader.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("READ ERROR");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }   

    try {   
        String line = "";
        while ((line = errReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.err.println(line);
        }
        errReader.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("READ ERROR");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }   

    return answer;
}
```

By the way the whole engine is working in a single seperate thread other than the main GUI thread. Therefore no overloading for the GUI. However i didnot seperate the stdin stderr and output methods in individual threads since i suppose there will be only stdin and the one that i will write to the engine. For the time being i assume they will not collide.

With these codes i am able to communicate with the engine and i can see the outputs in the console. However due to stdin.close(); i can only use this method once (In the seconds time i have a STREAM CLOSED error). The chess engine is needed to be communicated in command/response approach many times when opened, without restarting the exe in each time. **The problem is that if i remove the line : stdin.close(); yes the communication continues, but my console is blocked by this communication. I.e. i cannot println to the console for debugging purposes anymore.** Which is very critical because my main debugging weapon is system.out.println. If i do not remove stdin.close(); i have to restart executable each time i want to send message and i do not want that. **The strange part is that i can see the messages coming from the engine in my console due to "System.out.println(line);" line in the send method; however i cannot print anything on the console once the code exits the method. **

**EDIT:** Actually after this block:

```
while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);   
    answer = line;
}
```

System.out.println starts not to work.

**EDIT:** The problem seems not to be with println but any statement after while loop.

[Why statements after while loop is not getting executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667179/why-statements-after-while-loop-is-not-getting-executed)

according to this, it seems that since the stream is never closed, "while loop" is stuck(?). Actually when printing inside while loop, at some point(after a stream is finished), the prints stop, which must indicate while loop is finished. Therefore if it is finished, it should continue on the next statements, shouldn't it? Anyway, the messages from the engine had a set of strings at end of each stream; therefore when i encounter one of them i am breaking the while loop.

Note: it is also interesting that : accumulating data as: "receivedString += line"; doesnot work,i.e. data is not accumulated. In order to fix it i luckily made it "receivedString = receivedString + line + "\n""; and it worked.. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the input until end of stream, so it won't stop reading until end of stream occurs. End of stream means that the peer has closed the connection in this case. That won't happen for a process's output or error stream until the process exits. You'll have to find some other loop termination condition, or else consume the stdout and stderr in separate threads.